# using the arrow key in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textbox

I have two divs. One of them contains an input field the other a list of suggestions. What I would like is the ability for the user to come down in the second div with the use of the arrow key an also scroll through the list of suggestions. This is how it looks:

```
<div id="first"><input type="text" /></div>

<div id="second"> 
<ul>
<li>suggestion</li>
<li>suggestion2</li>
<li>suggestion3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I actualy found something here at Stack: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjKgF/5/)

But I can't make it work because it uses class names and I'm using ID's instead. 
I would very much appreciate if someone would rewrite this for me so I can append ID's.

Comment: your not asking a question - your asking for someone to do your work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a pretty simple change to get that fiddle to work how you wanted it:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_tesh/w6Zak/)

The class names were only there to highlight the selected item. The fiddle uses id's to reference the input and items wrapper. It wasn't much different than your code really. Now that you can see it working with your code you should be able to make and additional changes you see fit. Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** Woops. Looks like I forgot to update the fiddle. This has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks. The list in my script are actualy links(href).By using the arrow keys I thought I would be able to hit enter and then go to url. But now I realize that is a total different question. But that is oke because by analyzing the anwser provided by you and Cobra_Fast I was able to change many (other) things in my script which in the first place I had no idea of how to change. Thanks again very much.

Comment: No problem. Glad it was of some help. I was thinking you may want to hit enter and fill in the textbox, but if you wanted enter to go to the link, you could handle the enter key and change the `window.location` based on the `$(curr).attr("href")` pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use the onKeyDown event like

```
function KeyDownEvent(Event)
{
    if (Event.keyCode == 40) // down key was pressed 
    else if (Event.keyCode == 38) // up key was pressed
}

document.getElementById("textinput").onkeydown = KeyDownEvent;
```

Then your input HTML would look like:

```
<input type="text" id="textinput" />
```

Note that my example does **not** make use of the often unnecessary jQuery library.

In the actual events you would then change the style of the list items and save which value was selected by the user for autocompletion, which you should be able to figure out for yourself now.

Comment: thanks for your anwser. My script is very complex(to me..) so I cant make use of your anwser but you did point me in the right direction.